# How to enable payment/shipping method via fixture EComDev PHPUnit

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, payment, testing, ecomdev-phpunit

My purpose is to check whether certain values are properly set after I place an Order. As I am using a complete separate databse for unit testing purpose I don't have the Magento configuration available in the database.

I am trying to enable payment method and shipping method by inserting data through fixture in core_config_data table, by the following way

```
config:
    default/dev/template/allow_symlink: 1
    default/payment/purchaseorder/active: 1
    default/carriers/matrixrate/active: 1
```

But after running the test, when I check the test database table, I can't see those values in there. According to EcomDev_PHPUnit manual we can insert config data in that  way. 
What am I missing here? 
Is there something else I should consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

You did everything right, but you are looking in the wrong place. The original configuration is restored after the test (see `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Model_Fixture_Processor_Config`). So you only see the values in the database **during the test**, not afterwards.

Or better, verify in the test:

```
$this->assertEquals('1', Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/purchaseorder/active'));
```